# How to hide feature images from appearing in category listings?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Category in question - http://bodybackstory.com/before-and-after-weight-loss/

Right now you see 2 images for each post:

The first (cropped) image is the featured image. This is what I want
 to hide/remove from each post.

The second (bigger) image is one which has been manually inserted
 into each post and is being shown in the category listing because of
 a Read More tag.

I want to keep these images as featured images on most of the site because they are used as the source for thumbnails in related post functions.

How can I prevent each post's featured image from appearing in a category listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your featured images are in divs with `class="mediaBox image"`. Therefore, you can hide them using CSS as follows:

```
.mediaBox .image {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did just actually uncover this as well. The problem is of course that both images must be loaded still. It's a good band-aid but I would like to prevent the featured image from being loaded at all.

Comment: In that case, we might need to use php conditionals. Something like: `if ( !is_page ( 'page-slug' ) ) { echo '<div class="some-class-name"> </div>"}`. That way, they'll only be loaded when the page is not the page we don't want them to appear in.